# How to send image file in inputstream format to server using XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have four parameters in webservice. The service is working gud i have tested using android application. But the same thing i cant do in phonegap.

Parameters : name,emailid,pass and imagefile. Image was in format of base64png. In server side i am receiving as Inputstream. Looking for help to send as in binary format.

```
                    body+= ServiceHttpHeader('name',name1);
                    body+= ServiceHttpHeader('emailid',emailid1);
                    body+= ServiceHttpHeader('pass',pass1);
                    body +='Content-Disposition: form-data; name=imagedetails;'
                    body += 'filename='+imagedetails+'\r\n';
                    body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n "; 
                    body +=imgdetailurl+'\r\n';

                    body += '--' + boundary + '--';
                    ImageUploadRequest.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
                    ImageUploadRequest.send(body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap has its own API to upload images to a server.

One solution can be that you upload the image to the server first. On successful upload, you pass all the other parameters, along with the path of the file on the server, to another script, to perform whatever processing you want to be done there.

Phonegap's documentation says that one should not use base64 encoded images for upload, because that often causes an error for the latest high res camera images. Use FILE_URI instead. You can read more here.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera   (the documentation for camera.getPicture())

Example

```
function uploadPhotoToServer(imageURI)
{
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="img_file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    window.localStorage.setItem("upload_file_name",options.fileName);

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("<your image upload script url>"), onUploadSuccess, onFail, options);

}


function onUploadSuccess(r) 
{
    var filename = window.localStorage.getItem("upload_file_name");
    file_path_on_server = "path/to/images/folder"+filename;

       // other parameters
    var email = <the email Id> ;
    var name = <the name>;

    var parameters = "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&img_path="+file_path_on_server;

    $.ajax({
        url: <your current script url>,
        data: parameters ,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        timeout:10000,
        success:function(json) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(json, undefined,2));
        },
        error:function() {
            alert("Error");
        },
        type:"GET"
    });

function onFail()
{
       alert("Error");
}
```

Hope this helps.